# Android app displaying ads or app screen, not both

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

I am having trouble getting both my ads and my application to run at the same time. I have tried for two days to find a fix and nothing has worked. Please help.

This code displays my google play services Admob ads. - The ad displays but i cannot see my game screen, it is a black background.

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    private static final String TEST_DEVICE_ID = "8FB8CE7A6B82BA648ED21C697F4076";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

   initialize(new ZBGame(), cfg); 
   setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        // The "loadAdOnCreate" and "testDevices" XML attributes no longer available.
       AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
           .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
          .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
          .build();
       adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

This code (commented out ad code) runs my game successfully. 
What is causing the two to not work together?

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    private static final String TEST_DEVICE_ID = "8FB8CE7A6B82BA648ED21C697F4076";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

   initialize(new ZBGame(), cfg); 
  // setContentView(R.layout.main);  

//        // The "loadAdOnCreate" and "testDevices" XML attributes no longer available.
//       AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
//       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
//           .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
//          .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
//          .build();
//       adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
```

Hi William. I am just starting in Java and the tutorials I used were on http://www.kilobolt.com/zombie-bird-tutorial-flappy-bird-remake.html.

I did get the app and ads working as well. I realized after testing a while that the ad layout was replacing what i already had there (the game).

Utilizing the below code to get it working, which to my understanding. Creates a content view and adds both to it.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //gameViewParams.bottomMargin = 150;
        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        View gameView = initializeForView(new ZBGame(), cfg);
        layout.addView(gameView, gameViewParams);

        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4445204025228818/6510368088");
        //adView.setAdUnitId("app-id");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you haven't shown the code for #initialize, nor the XML config for R.layout.main but I suspect I can guess what is going on.

Since in the 2nd scenario your game works with #onCreate not calling #setContentView then #initialize must be calling #setContentView. THis means that in the first scenario you are calling #setContentView twice. You should only ever call this once as this defines the layout for your Activity.

Your layout needs to provide elements for your game and for the AdView. I suspect you do not yet have that. That will also need to be fixed.

Can you please post the link that you copied the game integration from. This is the 6th SO post I have seen using this code fragment and I would like to nip the source in the bud.

Comment: Hi William. I am just starting in Java and the tutorials I used were on http://www.kilobolt.com/zombie-bird-tutorial-flappy-bird-remake.html.

Comment: I have included the code i used to get everything working in my original post. What do you think?

Comment: I would recommend configuring your RelativeLayout in XML, then you can add your GameView and AdView to it. Doing your layout in XML will help you get a clearer picture of what your UI actually consists of.